# How to verify a package after downloading from repositories

Tags: ubuntu, debian, apt, packages, checksum

I have downloaded `filezilla` package using the command:

```
# apt download filezilla
```

So I have:

```
# ls 
filezilla_3.50.0-3_amd64.deb
```

## UPDATE

So I check sums:

```
# md5sum filezilla_3.50.0-3_amd64.deb 
a1a3180113e6b83ed278424a9d049877  filezilla_3.50.0-3_amd64.deb

# sha256sum filezilla_3.50.0-3_amd64.deb 
79667e6dfe3f8f70cc565ce95e34c48518c33f411cdbff97f848a3f345561535  filezilla_3.50.0-3_amd64.deb
```

But in [debian website](https://packages.debian.org/testing/all/filezilla-common/download) I see:

```
More information on filezilla-common_3.50.0-3_all.deb:
Exact Size  2300328 Byte (2.2 MByte)
MD5 checksum    4b3caf915076835f681f6b3ad4afd42d
SHA1 checksum   Not Available
SHA256 checksum ee6becd0e2faf421ab97f150c81f31beb5d5e6ac462c235f4b610924588ad8c8
```

What is the problem?
my repositories on debian are:

```
deb http://deb.debian.org/debian/ testing main
deb-src http://deb.debian.org/debian/ testing main

deb http://deb.debian.org/debian/ testing-updates main
deb-src http://deb.debian.org/debian/ testing-updates main

deb http://deb.debian.org/debian-security testing-security main
deb-src http://deb.debian.org/debian-security testing-security main
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [debsums](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/debsums.1.html)
to check the MD5 sums of installed Debian packages.

Debsums has several options.
For example, to verify installed packages and report only errors:

```
$ sudo debsums -s
```

For more information and examples of using debsums, see the article
[How to verify installed packages](https://blog.sleeplessbeastie.eu/2015/03/02/how-to-verify-installed-packages/).

Debian has been using strong crypto to validate downloaded packages since
2005 using digital signatures, so the downloaded file is guaranteed to be
exactly the same as in the repo. For more information see
[Secure Apt](https://wiki.debian.org/SecureApt).

For verifying the digital signature of a source package, see the post
[How to safely download and gpg verify a Debian source package?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/253728/how-to-safely-download-and-gpg-verify-a-debian-source-package)

Note: `filezilla-common_3.50.0-3_all.deb` and `filezilla_3.50.0-3_amd64.deb`
are two different packages. Check the
[Index of /ubuntu/pool/universe/f/filezilla](http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/f/filezilla/)
to find them both.

Comment: This is not true because I want to check only downloaded (by apt download) file not installed one.

Comment: Do you mean that you did `apt-get download` and you now wish to verify the `.deb` files? See my edited answer.

Comment: yes. for example I us `ar`  command to extract it and finally `tar xvf control.tar.xz`. so I can `cat md5sums`. But how can I get sure md5s are true from remote repo?

Comment: I updated the question

Comment: You are comparing two different packages - that's the difference.

Answer (score 0):

You can verify and know a lot about the .deb package using:

```
dpkg-deb --info filezilla_3.50.0-3_amd64.deb
```

Comment: How can get sure for details? Imagine my repos are manipulated by someone and I don't know. so I download the package and `--info` gives me the same result.

Comment: I updated the question